# fancyhdr doesn't put page number on final page

Tags: fancyhdr

In example 1, the page number doesn't appear on the final page.  This
is somehow bound up with defining the command `\theproperpage` within
the environment theplay, as is shown by the fact that example 2 does
the desired thing -- putting numbers on both pages.

== EXAMPLE 1

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\newcommand{\theproperpage}{} 

\newenvironment{theplay}  
               {\renewcommand{\theproperpage}{\thepage}}  
               {}  

\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyfoot{}    
\fancyhead[R]{\theproperpage}  


\begin{document}  
\begin{theplay}     

  blah  

  \newpage  

  blah  


\end{theplay}   
\end{document}
```

== EXAMPLE 2

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}  

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\newcommand{\theproperpage}{}  

\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyfoot{}  
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}  


\begin{document}  

\renewcommand{\theproperpage}{\thepage}  

  blah  

  \newpage  

  blah  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since the header is generated after the page is complete bur before the page counter is incremented, you don't have to worry about \thepage being off.  That only happens in a paragraph split over a page boundary.

Comment: You don't say what the intention of the code is, but `\fancyhead[R]{\theproperpage}` almost certainly does not work as desired. Use `\thepage` and for pages where you do not want the page number use `\thispagestyle{empty}`